# arranging image size matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I take an image by `imread()` but the size of the figure is different from the image. Also when I save the figure, the white/grey space around the image is considered a part of the image.

What I would like to have is to get an image, save it after some process and have an image with the same size and without white/grey space.

Actually, what I try to do is to draw a graph on an image by using NetworkX package and save the figure which I use somewhere else.

The code is simply like that;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 


G = nx.cycle_graph(80) 
pos = nx.circular_layout(G) 
img = mpimg.imread(path1) 
plt.imshow(img)

nx.draw(G,pos) 
nx.draw(G, pos=pos) 

plt.axis('off')
plt.show() 
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you're saving your image - you should probably use

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pp
pp.imwrite('savedimage.png', matrix)
```

and not the `savefig` option from a created figure - I would imagine that's where your border is being generated.

If you need to save the figure because there are other elements added to the plot, then you need to do three things,

- Resize the axis to fill the figure
- Make sure the figure has the same aspect ratio as your original image
- Set the `dpi` of the figure such that the saved image is of the same dimensions as the input image.

These are all done in `matplotlib`

Step 1:

```
ax = pp.gca()
ax.set_position([0,0,1,1])
```

Step 2:

```
asprat = float(img.shape[0])/img.shape[1]
sz = fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_figsize_inches([sz[0], asprat * sz[1])
```

Step 3:

```
fig.set_dpi( img.shape[0]/sz[0] )
```

Try that - I may have switched a dimension if the image is being plotted rotated or something.

Comment: @AhmetTuğrulBayrak: please append your code to the end of your question, it's not readable in a comment.

Comment: @AhmetTuğrulBayrak: please accept this answer if it's right, or let me know if it didn't work